# Can I declare a non-public method in an Objective C Category, and if so, how?

Tags: ios, objective-c

To work with JSON data I receive from the AFNetworking library in my app, I'm defining a category on NSDictionary in a file NSDictionary+JSON.h:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JSON)
- (NSString *) name;
- (NSString *) extension;
...
@end
```

In my implementation of these methods, I want to declare and use a helper method that I don't want to put in the header file, because it's an implementation detail only:

```
- (NSString *) valueForKeyFromDictionaryOrIndexes:(NSString *)key;
```

My implementation file NSDictionary+JSON.m looks like this:

```
#import "NSDictionary+JSON.h"

@interface NSDictionary()
// Putting my method declaration here produces a warning.
...
@end


@implementation NSDictionary (JSON)

- (NSString *) valueForKeyFromDictionaryOrIndexes:(NSString *)key {

    NSString * value = [self valueForKey:key];

    // implementation details omitted

    return value;
}

- (NSString *) name {

    return [self valueForKeyFromDictionaryOrIndexes:@"Name"];
}

- (NSString *) extension {

    return [self valueForKeyFromDictionaryOrIndexes:@"Extension"];
}

...

@end
```

This works fine, so in that sense there is no real problem. But: my helper method has never been declared before being defined. I feel a bit uncomfortable about that. If I put the declaration within the @interface ... @end part in the implementation file, at the comment position (which I assumed would be the correct place to declare a non-public method), I receive a warning:

> category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class

I tried fixing that by replacing
@interface NSDictionary()
with
@interface NSDictionary(JSON)
but that, of course, gives me a different warning:

> duplicate definition of category 'JSON' on interface 'NSDictionary'

Fair enough, that's indeed the same as the one in my header file, so that's not a proper solution. Which leaves me wondering: what's the proper way/place to declare a non-public method in a category implementation?

Comment: You need to put prefixes on methods you add to framework classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need at all to declare a "private" Obj-C method inside your `@interface`.

Comment: I noticed that it's not needed per se - it works without it. I guess my question is more: is not declaring it considered normal / good style in Objective C?